# how to generate Float and Text fields on symfony2/doctrine

Tags: symfony, text, doctrine-orm

I've made this doctrine entity for table creation:

```
class testtable
{


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11,  columnDefinition="INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
 */
protected $date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=TRUE)
 */
protected $lat;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=TRUE)
 */
protected $lng;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $log;
```

Now, I want two `floats` (`lat` & `lng`) fields and one `float` `log` field, but when I generate it I've got a different situation with two `double` fields and one `longtext` field

```
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| date           | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| lat            | double    | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| lng            | double    | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| log            | longtext  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

All is ok, but I want two `float` and one `text`, instead of two `double` and one `longtext`.

How do I fix it?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION FOUND, Resolved!
To force mysql type i need to insert columnDefinition="TEXT" and columnDefinition="FLOAT" tag into @ORM declaration like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=TRUE, columnDefinition="FLOAT")
 */
protected $lng2;
.
.
.
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", columnDefinition="TEXT")
 */
protected $log2;
```

So mysql give right results:

```
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
.
.
.
| lng2           | float     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
.
| log2           | text      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Thank you for all!

Comment: However you should make careful use of this feature and the consequences. SchemaTool will not detect changes on the column correctly anymore if you use “columnDefinition”.

Comment: I've got it! i became mad because the new "log2" was created by zero as "text", but "log"(already existing) have no changes applied, and it was always locked to "longtext"(though i had declared TEXT in columnDefinition).
To resolve it i had to destroy all, and recreate by zero entity and database. ^_^